# How could I check the cached data is fresh when using cache Interface?

Tags: javascript, caching

I've wondered how can I check my cached data is fresh when I used cache Interface of browser and JS.

I heard that a solution like this

1. define "lastFetchedTime" variable and set the time when I'm fetching
2. Compare current time and "lastFetchedTime" and if time interval is exceeding my reference (example 30s or any time I set), then re-fetch and caching.
3. If not exceed? then do nothing

```js
let cachedData;
let lastUpdated;

const checkFreshness = () => {
  const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  if (!lastUpdated || currentTime - lastUpdated > THRESHOLD) {
    // data is stale, make a new request
    fetchData().then(data => {
      cachedData = data;
      lastUpdated = new Date().getTime();
    });
  } else {
    // data is fresh, use cached data
    return cachedData;
  }
};

const fetchData = () => {
  // make API call to fetch data
};
```

Do this repeatidly.

Is this only way to check the cached data is fresh when using cache Interface?